# multiple RewriteRule in .htaccess doesnt work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with multiple RewriteRule in .htaccess.
Here is my code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=84]

RewriteRule ^stories$ kisah.php [L]
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [L]


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ kisahdetail.php?read=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ kisahdetail.php?read=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /choco/kisah.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /choco/kisah.php?cat=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

These codes are not working, 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /choco/kisah.php?cat=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /choco/kisah.php?cat=$1 [L]

whats wrong with that? A help would be apreciated

Comment: How would you imagine them to work, given that the previous rules practically match the same paths?

Comment: And what error you are getting on the Apache log ?
Check also that the Reg.Expression work: https://www.regextester.com/?fam=97698

Comment: @mario how should my code be? Help please

Comment: This isn't code. "Help please" nagging is redundant. And nobody can answer this, unless you let on what you want to accomplish. StackOverflow isn't about guessing what people want. Read some tutorials first: [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](//stackoverflow.com/q/20563772)